# How to convert mat to bitmap and bitmap to mat?

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap

Convert mat to bitmap and bitmap to mat .I got black scene. What could be reason, Someone help me please

```
 package com.example.alper.myapplication;

            import android.graphics.Bitmap;
            import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
            import android.os.Environment;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import org.opencv.android.Utils;
            import org.opencv.core.CvException;
            import org.opencv.core.CvType;
            import org.opencv.core.Mat;
            import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
            import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

            import static org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor;

    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ImageView iv;
        Bitmap bmpInput, bmpOutput;
        Mat matInput , matOutput;
        Button bt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/frames/frame.png";
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            bmpInput = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath,options);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmpInput);
            matInput = convertBitMap2Mat(bmpInput);
            matOutput = new Mat(matInput.rows(), matInput.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    bmpOutput = converMat2Bitmat(matOutput);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmpOutput);
                }
            });



        }
        Bitmap converMat2Bitmat (Mat img) {
            int width = img.width();
            int hight = img.height();


            Bitmap bmp;
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, hight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Mat tmp;
            tmp = img.channels()==1? new Mat(width, hight, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(1)): new Mat(width, hight, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(3));
            try {
                if (img.channels()==3)
                    cvtColor(img, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
                else if (img.channels()==1)
                    cvtColor(img, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
                Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
            }
            catch (CvException e){
                Log.d("Expection",e.getMessage());
            }
            return bmp;
        }


        Mat convertBitMap2Mat (Bitmap rgbaImage){
            Mat rgbaMat = new Mat(rgbaImage.getHeight(), rgbaImage.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);
            Bitmap bmp32 = rgbaImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, rgbaMat);

            Mat rgbMat = new Mat(rgbaImage.getHeight(), rgbaImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
            cvtColor(rgbaMat,rgbMat,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
            return rgbMat;
        }
```

I have a bitmap picture. ı want to convert to mat from bitmap and than ı apply some image process again convert  to bitmap from mat and than show at image view but ı got black scene .You think what could be reason ? help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions available in opencv for this in *Utils* class. Try using [these](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/Utils.html&ved=0ahUKEwiA4Mm7jKnRAhXEthQKHVRDBesQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNFVpmGuvaZCdE3wUJWngQt0UXUdyw&sig2=sL7odVFPuJNrb6yRIACVgA)

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your code. The error is in your image processing code.
If you try to convert bmpInput to mat and then reconvert it to bitmap, it'll work with your code.